# Angular installation problems

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I am following along with TutsPlus Real time web apps with angularjs and firebase.
Referring to https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular I ran

```
npm install -g grunt bower yo generator-karma generator-angular
```

After that I made a new project directory , cd into it and ran
`yo angular` which gave the following error:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn grunt ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
    at child_process.js:1137:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I have searched for ages now and can't find the specific reason for the error.
If someone could point me in the right direction please..
Thanks.

link to full output http://pastebin.com/GqJQV1Dg

Comment: Is there any more to that error message? Maybe dump the whole output to a pastebin and add the link to your question

Comment: Looks like it got most of the way through. I'd just re-run `bower install` and see what happens

Comment: Hi I ran bower install jquery and it has put the jquery files into bower_components/jquery/dist folder. So it looks OK but I am keeping fingers and toes crossed for the next test. Thanks for your advice!